# Should this answer's edit be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I just came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9190068). It was approved, but I can't decide if it was rightly approved or not.

I probably would have voted:

> "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

However, the code after the edit **is** correct and I'm not sure it needs rolling back. The older version is *slightly* wrong. There is a small syntax error.

**Should it be rolled back because it conflicts with the author's intent, or left alone because it is actually valid?**

---

It's interesting to note, out of the 5 reviewers on this question, two rejected, three approved, but only 2 (one vote each way) have decent knowledge on the subject (based on a quick look at their tag badges). The only thing I can really conclude from that is "robo-reviewers"

Comment: Realistically the edit should have been a comment, but, since it's an answer, and the edit did need to happen, i'd just move on and do nothing. Incorrect edit, but it did no harm, so no action needed.

Comment: @Trobbins I regularly edit code to fix formatting. I would hesitate to edit *actual code* (rather than whitespace) in a question, but would happily fix a typo in variable names, etc in answers.

Comment: People shouldn't be editing questions as a means of demonstrating a solution. I think mods should hand-hold these folks. This isn't relly good because it's misleading

Comment: @Trobbins well on the [when to edit section of the editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) , you can edit code "To correct minor mistakes".  Now that's only a good idea if you are familiar with the domain.  These edits are judged on technical accuracy in addition to other formatting.

Comment: @Trobbins That is strictly false.  Code edits (in answers) are no different than non-code content, namely you should maintain the author's intent, but are free to make changes if you can do so.  If there is a problem with the code that is clearly a mistake, i.e. a typo of a variable name, or simply forgetting something small that the author clearly *intended* to include, then fixing it is fine.  What's improper is adding code that they clearly didn't plan to write or changing something that you think is wrong that they went out of their way to explicitly do.

Comment: @Servy thanks. Removed my presumption.